# Python regular expression for words not starting and not ending with

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to construct regular expression in pythond for following rules,

1. Accept Words containing only alphabets
2. Words may contain - ( hypen)
3. word can not end with special character, for eg. `:)` ( pls consider these two)
4. Word can not start with _ (underscore) but may end with _ (underscore)

For eg.

Accept Words

```
Hello
Hello-World
Hello_
Hello1
```

Reject words

```
_hello_
hello:
hello:)
```

I have come up with following regular expression,

```
'(?!_)[\w-]+(?!:)'
```

It still accepts all words just skipping _ at the stat and : at the end,

Can somebody point, what's the wrong with my regular expression
Thanks

Comment: It's quite hard to tell what you're asking here. Can you explain, precisely, in words, what your regex should accept and reject (not just a list of examples).

Comment: Can you specify the concrete rules in text, in addition to examples (they alone don't explain the rules)

Comment: Pls find upated description

Comment: So your strings must start with alphabets? Or can it even start with say - `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a leading and trailing `\b`.

```
words = ["Hello", "Hello-World", "Hello_", "Hello1", "_hello_", "hello:",
         "hello:)" ]

import re

for word in words:
  print re.findall(r'\b(?!_)[\w-]+(?!:)\b', word)
```

Output:

```
['Hello']
['Hello-World']
['Hello_']
['Hello1']
[]
[]
[]
```

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

> `\b` Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character.

Comment: Omg, It just worked, I was missing 'r' and  \b, can you please explain a bit

Comment: @pradeep, check my edit. Also, you can use `^` at the start and `$` at the end if you want this to match the _complete_ string instead of the word, i.e., when your string will only have 1 word.

Answer (score 0):

There's still quite a bit of ambiguity in what you're asking for, but here's another solution for the sample set you gave, pre this [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/dpdma)

```
^[A-Za-z-]+[_\d]?$
```